# JPA Constructor Expression with an entire entity in param

Tags: hibernate, jpa, constructor, expression, entity

I'm trying to store the result of a query into a custom Pojo using JPA Constructor Expression

This works fine:

@Query("select new com.my.package.FinalDTO(c.id, SUM(p.revenue) as revenue) FROM Company c LEFT JOIN c.products p GROUP BY s")

However, in reality I will need around 25 fields from the Company Entity so

I was trying to do this instead of enumerating so much fields:

@Query("select new com.my.package.FinalDTO(c, SUM(p.revenue) as revenue) FROM Company c LEFT JOIN c.products p GROUP BY c")

But I get an error saying that hibernate is trying to store the c.id (which is a String) into a Long ?

The query I see in the logs doesn't seem to select all the company Entity but just the ID field:

```
select company0_.id as col_0_0_, sum(products1_.revenue) as col_1_0_ from...
```

Is it possible to store an entire Entity using the Constructor Expression ?